# Number of external displays supported on MSI GS63 stealth-060

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I just bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074VLX5XT) laptop off of amazon. Consequently I don't know the exact model number. My question is if I can connect 3 EXTERNAL displays to it.

The "matrix display" part of [this](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GS63-7RD-Stealth) product page says "supports up to 3 external displays simultaneously (three external or built-in + two external)" while [this](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=251279.0) fourm post claims that the GS60 series only supports "Built-in display + 2 external monitors". Which is it?

Comment: It supports 3 displays, one of those displays, is the laptop display.  You have to read the statement "three external or **built-in + two external**" very carefully.

Comment: Yes, but the first part of that statement was an alternate configuration in which 'three external displays' was an option.

Comment: It was an option for a different configuration of the product.

Comment: What do you mean by different configuration? That whole product page is talking about one product

Comment: ohh, got it. 2 ways to take it: 1) this laptop supports one or the other 2) this laptop supports both configurations. I was taking it as #2. you are taking it as #1

Comment: I assumed it was #2 since that page was dedicated to advertising one laptop. No reason to include an alternate config

Comment: The [specification](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GS63-7RD-Stealth) page you linked to lists several configurations.  MSI uses a single product page for all models of the Stealth (or so it appears to be the case)

Comment: where? I only see the one

Comment: "*GS73 / GS63 : 3 external displays through 1x HDMI (4K @ 60Hz), 1x Mini DisplayPort 1.2 and 1x Thunderbolt 3" and "*GS43 : 3 external displays through 1x HDMI (4K @ 30Hz), 1x Mini DisplayPort 1.2 and 1x Thunderbolt 3"

Comment: ah, sure enough! given I'm talking about the gs63, it would appear then that it does support 3 external displays! HDMI, mini displayport and thunderbolt!

Comment: I would trust the the comments of the moderator on the forum though.  I don't trust MSI to have accurate specifications based on what I have seen.

Comment: haha, good point. I was going to open a topic on their forum, but it's broken and won't allow for creation of new topics... nice.

Comment: The moderator is an MSI employee from what I can tell or an official spokesperson at the very least.  Which means the information they have or provided is likely correct.

Comment: If that's the case, I can't believe they actually picture their laptop in an impossible situation (pictured w/ lid closed driving 3 displays in product page)

Comment: @Ramhound hmm, another interesting twist. The forum post is from late 2014 which I believe refers to a much older GS model

Comment: As I point out, the product page appears to cover models of the Stealth, and even if it doesn't it likely is a case of marketing creating a stock image and web guys (knowing nothing about the product) using the same stock image for every version of the product SKU.  However, specific models of the Stealth do only support 2 external displays per the product page itself.

Comment: It's your source....Your laptop won't blow up if you connect three displays to it.

Comment: Yes, it was one of the only places I could find info about it, but I'm now realizing it might be out of date

Comment: oh, source as in output. Not understanding what that relates to at the moment

Comment: welp, we've gotten pretty far down the rabbit hole